# Placeholder that stay on text Field while typing Swift 3?

Tags: swift3, uitextfield, placeholder

I'm making an application which uses a Text Field. Now I want the Text Field to have a placeholder that stay small and on top of the field while I type, and doesn't disappear. Is it possible?

Comment: According to the answer of this [very related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523665/keep-the-placeholder-static-while-typing-in-uitextfield), you could simply add a UILabel above (or below) your text field.

Comment: Or if you want something more fancy you can use this (or some similar) library https://github.com/jverdi/JVFloatLabeledTextField

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep the Placeholder static while typing in UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523665/keep-the-placeholder-static-while-typing-in-uitextfield)

Comment: Thank you Michael, Eric and Jan. it works, but I want the text above appears just when I start typing... Possibly Jan's answer is the best for this ;)